# Searchview losing focus when method is called at listerner

Tags: android, android-widget

this is my code ,

when i type something text in searchview ,here some method is being called

**1.when i have result from the method ,the focus is lost**

**2.when i don't get result from the method, the focus is there.**

here i want even if i get the result ,the focus must be there in search view 
can anybody help.......

```
        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.d("**********", query.toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.d("**********", newText.toString());
                ***filItemAdapter("N", newText.toString());***
                searchview.setFocusable(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, here when i called the function filItemAdapter("N", newText.toString()) ,which has the edittext so when i get the result from the function, the focus is skipped into the edittext which in function, subsequently i found that the edittext has focus mode then i removed that focus mode later i called the focus mode where i exactly needed.

then its working fine, even i tried findinvalidate also which dosent work

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit, I just ran into the same issue and clearing focus from my views in my adapter doesn't give it back to the SearchView

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets the same issue,

You should update the searchview focus i.e mSearvhView.requestFocus(); in the search method, in my case I updated the focus in onBindViewHolder method of the adater.

Good luck